# What is the purpose of the "." parameter?

Tags: java

I saw on another question of how to read in exactly one character in Scanner this example...

```
char c = reader.next(".").charAt(0);
```

I was wondering what the `(".")` means. What is the difference between that and this: `char c = reader.next().charAt(0);`?

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs for [`next(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String))

> Returns the next token if it matches the pattern constructed from the specified string. If the match is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched the pattern.

And where in this example, `.` is

> a string specifying the pattern to scan

The difference between `char c = reader.next(".").charAt(0);` and

`reader.next().charAt(0);` is that `next(".")` returns the next token matching the pattern `.` and [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.